# Akka: unexpected mailbox filling up

Tags: java, akka

I have this simple code:

```
List<ActorRef> actors = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < ACTOR_COUNT; i++) {
    actors.add(system.actorOf(...));
}
for (ActorRef actor : actors) {
    system.scheduler().schedule(FiniteDuration.create(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
            FiniteDuration.create(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), actor, "Run", system.dispatcher(), null);
}
```

It creates a number of actors and then creates a scheduler for each of them. Actors itself are responsible for querying MQ and then process a message.

When ACTOR_COUNT > 30, everything is good. But otherwise, we have a memory leak (instances of akka.dispatch.Envelopes with message "Run" are filling up and can't be garbage collected)

It's pretty weird, because when we have more actors, then we have more messages (1 per second for each of them) - but unexpectedly it STOPS filling up when there are more actors/messages.

Time interval (1000 ms) doesn't really affect the situation, it just make it slower or faster.

Could you please explain this behavior for me?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Here is a dummy actor, which can help to isolate a problem.

```
public class MessageQueueTestActor extends UntypedActor {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageQueueTestActor.class);

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
}
```

The problem is reproduced with ACTOR_COUNT = 5. Now it's obvious that when actor sleep time > scheduler interval, envelopes are filling up. If I reduce sleep time from 3000ms to 500ms, the problem is gone.

*But messages also become available for garbage collector if I increase the number of actors up to 30 (with the same sleep time = 3000ms). Why? Looks like something in Akka starts working differently after that threashold.*

Comment: Honestly it does sound very strange. Can you maybe add the code of your actor's receive methods? Do you make use of become/unbecome?

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia I've updated the post, please have a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a «debug my code» question, not sure whether it should be here, but I'll answer in any case.

The scheduler does not enqueue the message into the actor’s mailbox itself, it uses the given dispatcher to do that. Since you block the threads in the default dispatcher and also use that to do the enqueueing, there is a point at which messages from the scheduler do not reach the mailboxes anymore (I assume that your default dispatcher has 30 threads). More correctly: they reach it one by one while the actors process up to five messages during each turn they get.

So, nothing is GC-ed, you just enqueue a different thing (Runnable) at a different place (default dispatcher). Your program will never work sustainably if the processing time is greater than the tick period.

Comment: Thank you. Ideed, magic number = our parallelism-factor * number of cores. Now it's clear.